# Is a Boolean automatically converted to a string when using jQuery .attr()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr, typeof

## Setup

So, in one area of my program, I am setting a custom html property to true:

```
$(document).on('click', '.profile-player-show', function(event) {
    $('.player-profile-pop').attr('inLineup', true);
}
```

Then, when that info is retrieved in another later function, I'm noticing that the boolean has a type of String now and it's not really a shock, I just want to know what the rules are...? Here is an example of my code in the latter:

```
var inLineup = $('.player-profile-pop').attr('inLineup');
console.log("In Lineup:" + inLineup + " Type of data:" + typeof inLineup);
var btnText = (inLineup === 'true') ? "Remove From Lineup" : "Add To Lineup";
```

## Findings

The console logs:

```
In Lineup:true Type of data:string
```

1. Only strings are allowed in html attributes

## My Question:

So, is a Boolean automatically converted to a string when using the jQuery .attr() function to set a variable such as true or false?

Comment: *[The content attribute is always a string even when the expected value should be an integer.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#Content_versus_IDL_attributes)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Attribute values can only be strings.

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks, but I wasn't asking if you can only have string sttribute values. I stated that I had found that. the question was: "is a Boolean automatically converted to a string when using the jQuery .attr() function to set a variable?"

Comment: @JoshuaMichael — That is a "Yes or No" question, and I said "Yes". And then I explained why.